# Is it possible to compile a c program with both static and dynamic libraries

Tags: c, linker

I know there is 2 ways to link libraries when we compile a c program:

- Static: The libraries are "embedded" inside the executable
- Dynamic: The libraries should be present on the file system. The executable depends on this libraries.

But is there a way to say when we compile a c program:

- This librarie should be statically embedded inside the executable
- This one should be linked dynamicaly ?

Thanks

Comment: `Is it possible` Yes. You can link with different libraries statically and and with different dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example:

```
gcc file1.c file2.c fileN.c ... -lfoo -lbar -lbaz --static -labc -lbcd -lcde
```

In this case, foo,bar,baz are linked dynamically, if available as dynamic libraries, otherwise static.

abc,bcd,cde are linked statically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that too

`gcc MyProg.c -Wl,-Bstatic -libS1 -libS2 -Wl,-Bdynamic -libD1 -o MyProg.exe`